# Unique filed according to admin id in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework and i have 3 fields in my table named Table_Details and fields are table_number,seats and admin_id.I want to enter a unique table_number for each admin_id.If i  use unique validation for field table_number,then it will insert table_number only once in the table but i want to insert table_number uniquely for each admin_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own rule. i.e.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       array('table_number', 'uniqueTable', "on" => "insert"),
    );
}
```

And define a `uniqueTable` function in your model:

```
public function uniqueTable($attribute,$params)
{
    $record=TableDetail::model()->findByAttributes(array('table_name'=>$this->table_name, "admin_id" => Yii::app->user->id));

    if(count($record) > 0){
        $this->addError($attribute, 'You already have a table with this name');
    }
}
```